# Proof: Every function $f(x,y):\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ is onto. Prove or Disprove

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

Claim: Every function $f(x,y):\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ is onto.

I think I want to prove this is true, using the definition of surjective.

If the co-domain is $\mathbb{R}$ then $f$ wil always output a horizontal line, which is always surjective.

This claim may be false, and I may be missing something.

---

**Edit:**I will disprove the claim with an example.

Comment: what about the constant function?

Comment: Rather, $f$ will output ***into*** a (horizontal) line, but (as the answers show) it may not output *onto* it.

Comment: @Zackkenyon Your simple comment was the best answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is definitely not true.  The easiest example is a constant function.  $f(x,y)=c$ for all $(x,y)\in\Bbb R^2$. For a less trivial example, consider $f(x,y)=x^2+y^2$. Here $f(\Bbb R^2)=[0,\infty)$.

Answer (score 3):

That is false in general; consider the map $f: (x,y) \mapsto \sin x: \Bbb{R}^{2} \to \Bbb{R}$.

Answer (score 0):

This statement is *extremely* not true.  It says ever single possible function must map, somehow by magic, to every single real number.  So to show this is false all we have to do is show that some function doesn't map to some number.

This is trivially easy.  Any function that positive value function never has negative out put.  Example $f(x,y) = (x + y)^2$.  Any function that only maps to an interval never has any value outside the interval.  Example $f(x,y) = \sin x$.  Any function that simply never equals a specific value never equals that value.  Example: for any function $g(x,y)$ let $f(x,y) = 0$ if $g(x,y) = 2; f(x,y) = g(x,y)$ otherwise, A constant function never equals anything except the constant.  Example: $f(x,y) = c$.

It's astonishingly easy to find functions that are not surjective. Any even powered polynomial, most exponential and logarithmic functions, any bounded function,  etc.

This is simply not true.